# Livedata don't update compose state when list item property has changed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

My problem is that live data observer is triggered `Observer<T> { state.value = it }` with the correct data but compose doesn't kick on recompose. Only when I add an item all changes are propagated. There must some checking on the list itself if it has changed. I guess it doens't compare list items.

```
@Composable
fun <R, T : R> LiveData<T>.observeAsState(initial: R): State<R> {
    val lifecycleOwner = LifecycleOwnerAmbient.current
    val state = remember { mutableStateOf(initial) }
    onCommit(this, lifecycleOwner) {
        val observer = Observer<T> { state.value = it }
        observe(lifecycleOwner, observer)
        onDispose { removeObserver(observer) }
    }
    return state
}
```

```
val items: List<TrackedActivityWithMetric> by vm.activities.observeAsState(mutableListOf())
```

```
 LazyColumnForIndexed(
        items = items,
        Modifier.padding(8.dp)
    ) { index, item ->
    ....
    MetricBlock(item.past[1], item.activity.id )

}
```

Comment: `MutableList` may be your problem. Mutable types in general are not a good thing with Compose. How are you modifying `items`?

Comment: It goes through Room and Viewmodel and both are correctly updated and the obser sees that.

Comment: Well, since I can't see that code, I cannot really comment on it. In the abstract, I would recommend avoiding `MutableList` and `var`.

Comment: If I put `.shuffled()` after I get the items from the DB all changes are reflected (In different order of course).

Comment: Same issue but sometimes it notify sometimes not for same data(sometimes means after restarting app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So behind the scenes there must be some kind hash comparing mechanism preventing rendering same item twice (More elabored answer wanted). The incorrect rendering was caused by property which was not in `TrackedActivityWithMetric` data class constructor.

Comment: Have you find a solution for this?

Comment: Same issue here - list item is not rendering if updated property is not in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Jetpack Compose does not work well with MutableList, you need to use a List and do something like this:

```
var myList: List<MyItem> by mutableStateOf(listOf())
    private set
```

for adding an item:

```
fun addItem(item: MyItem) {
    myList = myList + listOf(myItem)
}
```

for editing an item:

```
fun editItem(item: MyItem) {
    val index = myList.indexOf(myItem)
    myList = myList.toMutableList().also {
        it[index] = myItem
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this be observable? ie. will the UI recompose on addItem() ?

Comment: Yes, it will be observable